# Adjusting the height of a wkwebview programmatically

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I just started learning swift programming and got sucked into something.

I followed IAP tutorials on YouTube and successfully implemented AdMob banners and interstitial ads in my app. I was also able to turn off ads using the IAP. My question is:

I have a view in which I have two UI elements (`WKWebView`and a `GADBannerView`). The `WKWebView` element covers 90% of the screen starting from x:0,y:0, whereas the `GADBannerView` element covers 10%. I turned off ads and hid the `GADBannerView` element using IAP.

Now I want to dynamically/programmatically adjust the `WKWebView` size to fill the entire screen, i.e 100%. In other words, I want the `WKWebView` element to extend over the hidden `GADBannerView` element.

This is because hiding the `GADBannerView` leaves a blank field which is not cool to the view and the `WKWebView` looks truncated.

Please note that neither of the views are subviews. Both are independent views added separately. I understand that I can initially make the web view fill entire screen, add the `GADBannerView` on top of it, and when I remove ads and hid the `GADBannerView`, the web view will fill screen. That is not what I want because some content of the web view can not be seen using this approach. If I have a button at the end of HTML page that loads on the web view, this button can not be clicked because it will always be behind the gad banner view even when scrolling reached the bottom. Yes, you can scroll and hold to see the button, but once you release it, it will go back down.

So as a recap, I have two separate views and want to hid one and extend the length of the other to cover the entire screen.

Please tell me how to achieve that.

```
thirdBannerView.isHidden = true //Hide the banner view

//then code below to increase the size of the web view to equal device //screen width and height i.e full screen.

            func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: WKWebView) {
                //let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
               // let heightq = screenBounds.height
                //let widthq = screenBounds.width
                //webView.frame.size.height = heightq
                //webView.frame.size = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
                //webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthq, heightq);
                webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            }
```

This code is not effective at all as nothing changes. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: You almost definitely shouldn't be doing frame math in a modern mobile application it's an antiquated practice at this point. You should use constraints, pin the bottom of the web view to the top of the banner, and you can collapse the banner by giving it a 0 height.

Answer (score 0):

This particular scenario looks promising for applying `UIStackview`. Add your two view ( `WKWebview` and `GADBannerView`). apply fixed height for the `GADBannerview`. Whenever necessary just hide the `GADBannerview`.

Sample code

```
class StackviewController : UIViewController {
    let stackview: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .vertical
        view.distribution = .fill
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    // Your WKWebview here
    let sampleWKWebView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    // Your GADBannerView here
    let sampleGADBannerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(stackview)

        stackview.addArrangedSubview(sampleWKWebView)
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(sampleGADBannerView)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sampleGADBannerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
            ])


        // Enable this line to hide the GADBannerView
//        sampleGADBannerView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

**Here is the output**

[image]

I use two `UIView` to represent the `WKWebView` & `GADBannerView`. In the sample code uncomment the following to hide the bottom banner like green view.

```
sampleGADBannerView.isHidden = true
```

Comment: WkWebView can't be constructed without bounds which prevents to add it to the UIStackView.